# Eigenvector is unique for each of distinct Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that an nx1 vector x, which is not a null vector, cannot be an eigenvector of distinct eigenvalues lambda 1 and lambda 2

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $Ax=\lambda_1 x =\lambda_2 x$ then $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)x=0$, so...

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is a vector with eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, that means $Ax=\lambda_1x=\lambda_2x$,

which means $(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)x=0$.

From here it follows that $x=0$, which is not an eigenvector, or $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$.